# Html replacing radio button text

Tags: html

I wanna show a radio button with a Google maps. Is there a way to use Google maps instead of a string  for radio buttons.

I can show Google maps and a radio button.

But, i don't know how to replace radio button text with the google maps. Can you please help me?

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="inital-scale=1.0 , user-scalable=no" />
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>

        <script >
        function initialize() {

            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: fenway,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };

            var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>


<form>
<input type="radio" name="A" value="c1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="B" value="c2">2
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried here instead of just on jsfiddle?

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/D6ffv/" I did what i can understand from your query.

Comment: I can not see your jsfiddle. Could you please re-create it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiobuttons themselves do not have display text. You use a label to associate something clickable with a radiobutton, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo1" /><label for="foo1">Foo #1</label>
```

So, if you want to have something other than text be the "something clickable," simply replace the text with, in your case, a Google Maps widget.

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo1" />
<label for="foo1">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
</label>
```

**EDIT:**
Without seeing your CSS, you likely have something along the lines of this somewhere:

```
label
{
    display:block;
}
```

So try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="foo1" />
<label for="foo1" style="display:inline;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems work but I want to show the maps next to the radio button. Your case shows below it. How can I do it ?

Comment: @JohnSmith There are a lot of ways to do that. The easiest is probably to make sure your label has CSS to make it `display:inline` - try to figure that out yourself first, and if you can't get it, I'll update the sample.

Comment: @JohnSmith I can update the example, but your second question really needs to be a new SO question. The answer is, however, that you have two maps with the same ID, which is invalid; IDs must be unique.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I figured out that part... But, still I need to show the maps next to radio button .