# Use text act as a radio button / Make string into a radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want to make text work as a radio button for html, so from multiple options when i click one option (text) it get highlighted (selected) and carries value forward.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061380/html-replacing-radio-button-text

Comment: You want to have a piece of text (say a span) to behave like a radio button? What you are describing sounds eerily like a `select` with a `size` attribute, you know that? And I don't understand what you mean by "carries value forward". Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes you're right, I just want a text span to work like a radio button, and by carring value means when I click (select) a radio button which I want to be in form of text, it should pass its value like actual checked radio button do on submition.

Comment: Still sounds like a `select` with a `size` attribute...

Comment: Yea but not exactly select tag, here is the link of the page http://www.hashtaginc.us/Projects/Relax/sss.html
See the options, I want to make them work like radio button. When I click it, it should get highlighted (selected)

Comment: That should have been part of the question, it would have made it easier to find out what you needed exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to simply use radio buttons, which you make invisible. Then turn the texts into labels for the radio buttons.
I put each of the radio buttons and its label in a wrapper, to make positioning them easier.

```
<div class="radiowrapper" id="wrap1">
    <input type="radio" name="problem" value="headaches" id="problem1">
    <label for="problem1">I get headaches</label>
</div>
<div class="radiowrapper" id="wrap2">
    <input type="radio" name="problem" value="teeth" id="problem2">
    <label for="problem2">I grind my teeth</label>
</div>
<div class="radiowrapper" id="wrap3">
    <input type="radio" name="problem" value="heartburn" id="problem3">
    <label for="problem3">I experience heart burn</label>
</div>
```

And the css:

```css
.radiowrapper {position:absolute;}

.radiowrapper input {visibility:hidden; width:0;}

.radiowrapper label:hover {font-weight:bold}

.radiowrapper input:checked + label {font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase}

#wrap1 {left:100px; top:50px;}

#wrap2 {left:80px; top:100px;}

#wrap3 {left:0px; top:150px;}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n5UnK/6/).